# split an output of a command and search for a word in expect

Tags: text-processing, expect

I have this chunk of code that I want it to read output of a command, substring it from the beginning to a special character and then if that part is not empty send_log that it passed. But I'm not sure how to do it. Here is waht I got so far.

```
#!/opt/tools/unsupported/expect-5.39/bin/expect

spawn ssh -l $USER $VMIP_1
expect_after eof {exit 0}
set timeout 10
match_max 256

expect "(yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
expect "password:" { send "$PASSWORD\r" }

expect "~]#" { send "date\r" }

expect "~]#" { send "pidof snmpd\r" }
sleep 5
expect "~]#" {
set buf [split $expect_out(buffer) "[root@"]
if {[lindex $buf 0] !=="" }
{
        log_file /home/bebehman/vnf/trunk/report.txt
                 send_log "Verify net-snmp installation and functionality on $VMIP_1--------------------- Passed\n"
    } else { send_log "Verify net-snmp installation and functionality on $VMIP_1--------------------- Failed\n"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `split` does not work as you seem to think. It does not split on a word, but on any character given in the second string. For example `split "xax" "abc"` will indeed split `xax` into 2 parts, despite it not containing the sequence `abc`.

A simple way to split a string at a given substring is, for example, using the `string first` command to find the start of the substring, then `string range` to copy up to that point:

```
set str $expect_out(buffer)
set v [string range $str 0 [string first "\[root@" $str]-1]
```

You can then test `v` for empty or not.

Alternatively, instead of doing `expect "~]#"`, why not `expect "\[root@"`, then `$expect_out(buffer)` will already contain what you wanted to extract.

---

For earlier versions of tcl/expect, you may need to use `expr` to subtract 1 from the index instead of letting `string range` accept the form number-number.  So use, for example:

```
set v [string range $str 0 [expr [string first "\[root@" $str] - 1]]
```

Comment: thanks. I will try this way. I started tcl two weeks ago and I'm learning a lot. I wanted to rate your answer but I don't have enough credit here I guess.

Comment: @behnaz, there are very few syntax rules in Tcl. They are all listed here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: @meuh I get this error : bad index "21-1": must be integer or end?-integer?
    while executing

Comment: @glennjackman thank you. I had this open since I started working with tcl last week but when I put them to test still I need to know more in action.

Comment: @behnazbehmanesh I was using a slightly more recent version of tcl/expect than you. I added to my answer what to do for your version.

Answer (score 0):

```
if {[lindex $buf 0] !=="" }
{
```

wont compile; instead you need this

```
if { [lindex $buf 0] != "" } {
```

Comment: I edit that thanks. The checking in if statement for the split string not to be blank is fine?

Comment: You have 2 equals !== it should be !=